# Dynamic Sql - Creating a database - Problems with syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error, dynamic-sql

I'm having issues with a dynamic SQL script in particular this bit:EXEC('

```
if db_id(''' + $(db) + ''') is null
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE ' + $(db) + '
END
```

The if statement part seems to work fine, I know this because if the database exists then the create database line is not run but  when it needs to run I just get syntax errors near that line.

I have also tried:

```
CREATE DATABASE ''' + $(db) + '''
```

with no luck

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why you have a dollar sign in your DB name? in your above question you are trying to create a database with name as `' + $(db) + '`. This violates the Sql server identifier name rules please read this [`Rules for Regular Identifiers`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Its Dynamic Sql and the DB name is passed in, it works perfectly for the if statement just not the create database bit.

Comment: What ever string I pass in through the command line

Comment: what do you want your database name to be ? It is working fine for IF statement because if statement doesnt have to create this database it just checks if there is a database with this name or not, On the other hand Create statement checks if the passed name is in compliant with identifier rules and errors out as you proposed name violates that, Please read the link mentioned above in my comment. thank you

Comment: Ok well the string I am passing in at the moment is Test1 so I don't think I am violating any thing

Comment: The way you are passing this string sql server is trying to create a database with name `' + $(db) + '`. You have all these characters `' + $(` in the beging of your database name, The first letter in your database name must be an alphabet a-Z according to MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DB_NAME NVARCHAR(128) = N'Test_DB'
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF DB_ID(@DB_NAME) IS NULL
BEGIN
   SET @Sql = N' CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DB_NAME)

   EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

**Important Note**

Make sure your database name is in accordance with the [`Rules for Regular Identifiers`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)